# Unit testing a controller action method using MOQ

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I have the following controller action method.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateProvider(Provider provider)
    {
        try
        {
            int providerCreationSuccessful = _repository.CreateProvider(provider);
            if (providerCreationSuccessful == 2)
                TempData["userIntimation"] = "Provider Registered Successfully";

            //return RedirectToAction("ShowTheListOfProviders");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(Ex.Message);
            return View("Error");
        }
        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("ShowTheListOfProviders", "Provider") });
    }
```

I had written the following Test case for the above method,which **was working**

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void CreateProviderTest()
    {
        mockProviderRepository.Setup(provider => provider.CreateProvider(_provider)).Returns(new int());
        var providerCreationResult = _providerController.CreateProvider(_provider) as ActionResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(providerCreationResult);
    }
```

As can be seen from my code in the action method,I am redirecting using AJAX,hence returning JSON of the url to be redirected to.

Now,the test is obviously failing.I am new to unit tests and was wondering,what updates I needed to make to the Testmethod for it to pass.Please guide me.Thanks.

Comment: Is there a error being thrown?

Comment: The method in the repository returns an integer.Since I am MOQing the database access,I have added that.The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".This error is thrown where I am returning JSON

Comment: Yes,there is an error being thrown.Please check my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want test the Json Result contains the expected URL, you can write a test like below.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateProvider_Execute_EnsureJsonContainsExpectedUrl()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();

    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    request.SetupGet(x => x.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
    request.SetupGet(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost/a", UriKind.Absolute));
    response.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(x => x);

    context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(new RouteCollection());

    var repoStub = new Mock<IRepository>();
    repoStub.Setup(x => x.CreateProvider(new Provider())).Returns(1);

    var sut = new HomeController(repoStub.Object, new Mock<ILogger>().Object);

    sut.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData()), routes);

    var result = sut.CreateProvider(new Provider()) as JsonResult;
    var actualUrl = GetValueFromJsonResult<string>(result, "url");
    Assert.AreEqual<string>("/Provider/ShowTheListOfProviders", actualUrl);
}


private T GetValueFromJsonResult<T>(JsonResult jsonResult, string propertyName)
 {
     var property =
         jsonResult.Data.GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => string.Compare(p.Name, propertyName) == 0)
                .FirstOrDefault();

     if (null == property)
                throw new ArgumentException("propertyName not found", "propertyName");
            return (T)property.GetValue(jsonResult.Data, null);
 }
```